# One Service Worker Process stop another Service Worker Process and Vice Versa

Tags: android, push-notification, polymer, service-worker, onesignal

We are using the platinum service worker (Google Polymer Element) for offline and Caching feature of our app. When we open our app for first time the service worker of polymer element starts running. The app works fine.

But as soon as we Subscribe to One Signal (3rd Party) for push notification, their Service worker runs and our platinum service worker stops running (un-register). The same case happens when we again reload our app the one signal service worker stops running (un-register) and the platinum service worker starts running.

We want both the service worker works independently without effecting one another. Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: did you ever find out how to best integrate onesignal? i'm using sw-precache and facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Our service workers `OneSignalSDKWorker.js` and `OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js`overwrite other service workers that are registered with the topmost (site root) service worker scope; would it be possible to import your other service workers into our service worker alternatively?

Here's how to do that:

Currently the contents contents of both `OneSignalSDKWorker.js` and `OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js` contain the following:

```
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js');
```

Please modify both the contents of `OneSignalSDKWorker.js` and `OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js` to import your other service worker files like this:

```
importScripts('https://example.com/my-other-service-worker.js');
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js');
```

We recommend the above approach instead of importing our service worker into another file because our web SDK overwrites out other workers that are registered on the root scope and replaces them with our ours.

Please note that all this only applies if you're trying to register service workers to the root scope like https://example.com/other-worker.js. If you're trying to register a service worker under a specific sub-directory only like https://example.com/some-subdirectory/other-worker.js, then your service worker should not be replaced.

More about service workers [can be read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

Comment: if i want import with relative path to other-service-worker.js, it's still not work

Comment: The issue with importing other offline caching scripts into one signal file is that if I decide to remove one signal from my app in the future the data will be cached and will require my users to manually clear site storage and cache to remove one signal vode

Comment: I'm using Sw-precache and facing the same issue as the original poster. any update on this matter @onesignal  because my swpreacche service worker is overwritten everytime by onesignal SW.